# Typoscript Redirect additionalHeaders with parameter

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I tried to catch an URL Get-Parameter from the entry URL and redirect it to the redirect URL.

```
Entry-URL: https://my-domain.de/firstPage?myParam=123
 

      config.additionalHeaders.10 {
        header.data = gp:myParam
        #Redirect-URL: https://my-domain.de/secondPage
        header = Location: https://my-domain.de/secondPage?myNewParam={gp:myParam}
      }
```

I tried it with "header.data", "additionalParams", but nothing worked.

Does someone has an idea?

Many thanks.

Comment: The documention says nothing about stdWrap functionality of header property:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#additionalheaders
So maybe go with a redirect in the redirect module or a custom PSR-15 middleware.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Is there no solution, to do it with typoscript? Any other ideo to do it with typoscript?

Comment: by TypoScript you can try to add a custom meta-tag with a redirect instruction, but it's not a very nice solution.

Comment: could you please give me a hint regarding the typoscript code? I have no idea how to do it? Thanks a lot